# How can I convert 3.5 Generic Classes to Pathfinder?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

I recently obtained the Pathfinder Core Rulebook, and I'm really impressed by the changes. I am going to change my campaign from  3.5e to Pathfinder, but I'm stuck on one major thing.

In our campaign, we were using the ["Generic Classes" variant](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/genericClasses.htm), so as sort of z sidequest, the characters would go out in to the world seeking "masters" in order to convert their generic class levels to actual class levels.

However, I've looked through the Pathfinder Conversion Guide, and while it does a pretty good job of converting core classes to Pathfinder, it doesn't do much for anything else. Since almost everything should be backwards compatible, I can just do a simple conversion to Pathfinder, but then I'm worried that the characters will be underpowered.

What is the easiest way to covert Generic Classes into Pathfinder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has come up on the [Paizo boards before](http://paizo.com/paizo/messageboards/paizoPublishing/pathfinder/pathfinderRPG/houseRules/pathfinderGenericClasses) but as far as I am aware no one has finished their work.

Short answer is there's no *easy* way to do it, but you should be able to take the suggestions in the Conversion Guide for converting the core classes and apply it to the generic classes as presented on the d20 SRD.

The generic modifications (Hit Die, saves, etc) are going to be fairly trivial, the hard part is going to be selecting which class features you'd allow as "feats". If you are interested in going that route, I would suggest you start with some of the abilities from Fighter, Monk, Sorcerer (from the "default" bloodline), and Cleric and add some of the class features from those. But there's no "correct" way to do that. You also need to remember that Pathfinder has a tendency to ramp the power levels of all classes, bonus feats, class abilities, etc, so that needs to play a factor in your conversion.

Alternatively, and I almost prefer this suggestion, is to take the NPC classes presented in the Pathfinder Core book, and modify them to have PC BAB, Saves, and other class features. So, for example you'd be playing an Adept with a higher BAB, and better Saves (probably following the Cleric Progression), but with Adept abilities and spell lists. You'd have to expand their abilities further on if you plan on playing a long time like that...

So, yeah, no easy answer, hopefully this will help give you some ideas.

Comment: I really like the NPC class idea.