# Are there rules creating/rewriting/converting classes for Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, conversion

I was hoping to rewrite the Duskblade for Pathfinder, but I wanted to know if there are specific rules I can find on converting D&D 3.x classes to Pathfinder. Are there?

Comment: Related: [How can I convert 3.5 Generic Classes to Pathfinder?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/8242)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but they require quite a lot of experience with the games in question. But there are a depressing number of conversations [here](http://paizo.com/paizo/messageboards/paizoPublishing/pathfinder/pathfinderRPG/conversions). Unfortunately there's a [whole book that attempts this discussion -- your mileage may vary](http://paizo.com/products/btpy89m6?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Conversion-Guide). Needing to do this level of homebrew is likely a sign of insufficient system mastery, a love of graven idols, and a need for a better system that supports your requirements.

You also need to have a thorough [knowledge of the literature](http://www-public.jcu.edu.au/libcomp/assist/training/JCUPRD_026319): what do people involved in that system's community think about various aspects of the rules as they relate to mechanisms of your class. *Why* do they think that way? What are the settled issues? What are the controversial issues? Why are they controversial? All of this discussion is a record of the knowledge and mistakes people have made *so you don't have to.* Given that you didn't bother to google (or your searches failed to find results) for this in the first place, I would recommend against the practice until you've improved your searching skills. To quote the academic reasoning for lit reviews:

> It makes no sense to start a research project without knowing what work has already been done by others. Wouldn't it be embarrassing to unknowingly repeat what others have already done?

There's quite a lot of discussion [around current efforts](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2kzqf?Converting-all-35-Base-Classes-to-Pathfinder) to convert classes, especially with regards to the duskblade. With that said, using and choosing conversions requires a deep system mastery and the expertise that comes of having played a few campaigns with different players to get a sense of *how* and *in what direction* conversion choice will break. Layering complexity *on top* of custom homebrew is **severely disrecommended.**

Gaining system mastery, and more importantly, expertise in GMing is critical before hacking rules. Once you've run a campaign and have the necessary chops for building characters out to level 20 *with an understanding* of what choices are made at every level and why, with complex prestige class choices, *then* start poking your head into the murky world of homebrew classes. Duskblades (unlike binders) are not sufficiently original that they cannot be reproduced.